# "Unexpected Tokens" in OCaml and debugging

Tags: ocaml

so I am having trouble with debugging in OCaml. The problem is that I am writing very simple code, but I keep getting a problem that seems easy to fix - i just don't know how!

```
    let rec multiplier (int1: int) (int2: int) (int3: int) : int =
    let product : int
if int1 >= int2 then(
    if int1 >= int3 then product = int1 * int2
    else product = int1 * int3
)
else if int2 >= int1 then( 
    if int1 >= int3 then product = int2 * int1
    else product = int2 * int3 
)
```

I keep getting a red 'x' and a squigley line under the first "if" with the error : "Unexpected token: if"

Thanks!

Comment: Your trouble is not in debugging Ocaml, it is to understand Ocaml's concepts and syntax. You did not start debugging your program before it compiles cleanly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think of `=` be an assignment; there basically is no assignment in Ocaml (except `:=` used for references).

Write something like

```
 let area : int = 
   if side1 >= side2 then ( 
     if side2 >= side3 then side1 * side3
     else side1 * side3
    )
   else if side2 >= side1 then ( 
     if side1 >= side3 then side2 * side1
     else side2 * side3
   )
   else 0
```

Remember that the `if` ... `then` .... `else` .... construct is an expression; it is more like the ternary `?:` conditional operator of C than like its `if` statement.

Remember that Ocaml don't have statements, only expressions. (Its `;` operator e.g `a;b`  is similar to C comma operator `a,b` meaning compute `a`, discard the result, and compute `b` giving its result for the whole expression)

Comment: Ok so I fixed that. Thank you! 
But now I get a syntax error and an "unexpected token"  bug in the my next function.

Comment: You have to learn Ocaml's syntax. Did you re-read http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.00/language.html ; you should read it several times, and refer to relevant parts when coding.

Comment: Well, there is assignment using `<-` for array elements, string elements, and mutable fields of records. But, yes, you cannot "assign" to a variable.

Comment: I don't call that an assignment, it is a mutation operation. It mutates some contents inside values, it does not change values of variables.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Much appreciated! I think I've got the hang of it.